# Impossible to kill processes via SNMP

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I'm trying to kill processes using SNMP.
 I know that is possible setting to 4 the "status" field of a process like:

`snmpset -v 2c -c community_string ipaddress 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.7.PID i 4`

I always receive the same message:

> Error in packet.
>   Reason: not Writable (That Object does not support modification)
>   Failed object: iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.7.PID

I don't know why, but this also happens when I use the "localhost" that normally has all the privileges. Maybe there is something wrong in my settings? This is my snmpd.conf file:

```html
#  AGENT BEHAVIOUR
#

#  Listen for connections from the local system only
agentAddress  udp:161
#  Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6)
#agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161
```

```html
###############################################################################
#
#  ACCESS CONTROL
#

                                                 #  system + hrSystem groups only
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1

                                                 #  Full access from the local host
rwcommunity public  localhost

rwcommunity ubuntulaptop
                                                 #  Default access to basic system info
 rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
                                                 #  rocommunity6 is for IPv6
 rocommunity6 public  default   -V systemonly

                                                 #  Full access from an example network
                                                 #     Adjust this network address to match your local
                                                 #     settings, change the community string,
                                                 #     and check the 'agentAddress' setting above
#rocommunity secret  10.0.0.0/16

                                                 #  Full read-only access for SNMPv3
 rouser   authOnlyUser
                                                 #  Full write access for encrypted requests
                                                 #     Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
#rwuser   authPrivUser   priv

#  It's no longer typically necessary to use the full 'com2sec/group/access' configuration
#  r[ow]user and r[ow]community, together with suitable views, should cover most requirements



###############################################################################
#
#  SYSTEM INFORMATION
#

#  Note that setting these values here, results in the corresponding MIB objects being 'read-only'
#  See snmpd.conf(5) for more details
sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>
                                                 # Application + End-to-End layers
sysServices    72


#
#  Process Monitoring
#
                               # At least one  'mountd' process
proc  mountd
                               # No more than 4 'ntalkd' processes - 0 is OK
proc  ntalkd    4
                               # At least one 'sendmail' process, but no more than 10
proc  sendmail 10 1

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::prTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table will be empty if there are no "proc" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
#  Disk Monitoring
#
                               # 10MBs required on root disk, 5% free on /var, 10% free on all other disks
disk       /     10000
disk       /var  5%
includeAllDisks  10%

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::dskTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table will be empty if there are no "disk" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
#  System Load
#
                               # Unacceptable 1-, 5-, and 15-minute load averages
load   12 10 5

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::laTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table *will* be populated, even without a "load" entry in the snmpd.conf file
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error in packet. Reason: not Writable (That Object does not support >modification) Failed object: iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.7.PID

This message above is probably just what it says. The variable is a read-only and cant be edited. If the variable is writable or not is specified in the MIB. You better check the MIB first. If a variable is read-only it doesnt matter what you do.

Killing processes with SNMP, as far as i know, is not that usual. At least you usually do not do it in that way. SNMP is for managing the network. But again if you have a proprietary MIB you must check it and see what it says there.